# How to get the value of a checkbox in VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have the below code in a VF page and a simple javascript function to get the value of the checkbox. However, irrespective of whether the checkbox is checked or not I get a value of "on". How do I get the correct value of the checkbox ?

```
<apex:inputCheckbox id="cb1" value="{!cbVal1}" onchange="foo('{!$Component.cb1}', '{!$Component.cb2}',);
<apex:inputCheckbox id="cb2" value="{!cbVal2}" onchange="foo('{!$Component.cb1}', '{!$Component.cb2}',);

 <script type="text/javascript">        
     var foo = function foo( shp , con ){
        console.log( 'shp : ', document.getElementById(shp).value );
        console.log( 'con : ', document.getElementById(con).value );
    }
</script>
```

Console output is :

"shp : " "on"

"con : " "on"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer - `checked` attribute gives the right value

`document.getElementById(shp).checked`